# Route not found exception in Laravel Blade View - Route [user.update] not defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have defined route in Route File as :

```
Route::get('user/update','Users@Update');
```

I want to fill my model data to form so i am writing `form::model`

```
<?php echo Form::model($users,array('route' => array('user.update', $users->id))) ?>
```

It show me error :

```
Route [user.update] not defined.
```

If i write

```
<?php echo Form::model($users) ?>
```

Then it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default method created by the Form class is "POST", so you need:

1) to **name** the route (as correctly pointed out by @Joel);

2) to make it answer to the proper **HTTP verb**:

```
Route::post('user/{id}/update',['as' => 'user.update', 'uses' => 'Users@Update']);
```

If you're using it for both GET and POST, use the `any` method:

```
Route::any('user/{id}/update',['as' => 'user.update', 'uses' => 'Users@Update']);
```

Comment: Oops, forgot that post is needed for the Form::model. Thanks for the correction, I'll delete my answer.